# Getting sqlite3.OperationalError: not authorized while loading an extension in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am trying to load these extensions
`libsqlite3.so.0`, `json1` in order to execute MySQL functions `json_contains_path` in sqlite3

but while running this I get an error

here's what I have done so far `sqlite3.OperationalError: not authorized`

here is my code

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
connection.execute("PRAGMA enable_load_extension = 1")
connection.execute("SELECT load_extension('libsqlite3.so.0', 'json1')")
```

I am running unit test cases so my db is created in memory.

OS: Mac OS

Comment: What version of sqlite do you have?  As of version 3.38, all of the json1 extension is now included in the sqlite core.

Comment: @TimRoberts, its running on 3.32

Answer (score 1):

There is no such pragma.  You would need to call

```
connection.enable_load_extension(True)
```

HOWEVER, by default, the underlying sqlite3 library on MacOS is not built with extensions enabled at all.  You would have to build the library yourself.

Reference https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Overall, it's probably much easier just to implement the functionality you need in your Python code.